# $ g(u;s_1,s_2)=\int_{(\alpha+\beta)^{-1}}^{\alpha+\beta}b^{s_2}(u^2-b)^{-\dfrac{s_1+s_2}{2}}(u^2b-1)^{-\dfrac{s_1+s_2}{2}} \mathrm {d}b$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Do you have any idea how to compute this function?

$$ \displaystyle g(u;s_1,s_2)=\int_{(\alpha+\beta)^{-1}}^{\alpha+\beta}b^{s_2}(u^2-b)^{-\dfrac{s_1+s_2}{2}}(u^2b-1)^{-\dfrac{s_1+s_2}{2}} \mathrm {d}b$$

Where $\alpha>1>\beta>0$, $u\in (\alpha-\beta,\alpha+\beta)$ and $s_1,s_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Thank you very much